# will a manually updated stack in AWS that was created with cloudformation cause conflicts in the future?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am using cloudformation to deploy/update some stacks, including RDS. At the moment I successfully created my database and I want to update the port since I set the wrong one.

Reading the docs I encounter that by updating it via cloudformation, I must rename the stack in order to be able to update the port, therefore it will just create a new RDS instance with the new port and destroy the old one, this means I must create a backup first and later restore it.

I was reading that updating the port "manually" from the AWS console does not behave that way and no data loss should happen, so far I have not tried.

So, for example:

My deployed cloudformation is the following:

cloudformation template -> port 123
deployed stack -> port 123

I need to update it to port 234

then my cloudformation will still know the latest deploy happen to port 123
deployed stack -> 234 (the updated via aws console)

My question is the following: In the case, I am able to update the port via AWS Console, what will happen with the cloudformation template? should I update the template to have port 234 or I should leave it with port 123 so it wont try to make an update? (that would cause inconsistency on what I have at the template and what is really deployed but I wonder if would work)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html#update-replacement

I dont have problems with all the vpc, security groups, rules, etc,  its basically just the port.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify resources manually outside in AWS console (or CLI, SDK) which were created by CFN  is a bad practice which results in a [stack drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html). The drift can lead to future issues; from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html):

> Regardless, changes made outside of CloudFormation can **complicate stack update or deletion operations**.

Specifically to answer your question:

> In the case, I am able to update the port via AWS Console, what will happen with the cloudformation template?

Nothing will happen per-se. CFN will not be aware by itself of any changes made to your RDS outside of CFN. But your stack will be considered as **drifted**, which, as AWS docs write, can lead to issues. Thus its **better to avoid** such situation.

> should I update the template to have port 234 or I should leave it with port 123 so it wont try to make an update?

Yes, if you want to avoid drift. But updating port through CFN will lead to **replacement** of your db instance and data lost. So you must take all precautions on how to do it. Best would be to create some dummy RDS db, and do a test-run on it to understand the procedure and consequences of changing its port.